# Is typeid safe being used on pointer provided by another process, which is compiled by the same compiler?

Tags: c++, typeid

According to the standard, typeid operator is implement dependent, so it's nonsense to use it on objects created by other processes compiled by different compiler. But what is the situation that the providing process is compiled by the same compiler?

Comment: Why do you need to know the type? It could indicate a broken design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably won't work because the foreign object will contain a vtable pointer within its own process space, not that of the inspecting process. If you can form an address space where both executable binary images are in place as if they were the one running, then maybe. If it's the same version of the same compiler used with identical command-line flags, or if your platform ABI specifies exactly how `typeid` works at runtime, then you might be OK.

But strictly speaking, the C++ object model does not accommodate shared memory. You need to serialize before transmitting between processes, and there is no way to safely serialize a C++ type which might not exist on the receiving end.

Comment: Well, I didn't take account of memory sharing issue. If all the classes are defined in a library, and each process's executable is linked to the library, so they both have the classes definition. Will it work?

Comment: @LiuYongtai most OSes employ address space randomization specifically to prevent this from happening. The problem is that such a strategy is more useful to a virus trying to spread between or control external applications than for legitimate use. You might be able to get your OS to load the library into the same virtual address range in every process, but it's probably not a good strategy, and any OS might remove support for doing so in the future.